# How to find the public name of a contact on Viber?

Tags: viber-messenger

I have added a new viber contact, but it (correctly) displays the contact with the name I've used in my contact book. Nevertheless, I want to view my contact's "public" name, the one that my contact has chosen to "advertise". It's the username you set up when creating a new viber account. How can I see this?

My contact has been able to see my "public" name, I assume before saving my phone number in their own contact book, so it is definitely advertised.

Answer (score 2):

It goes when you delete the contact off your local contact list and then you intend to add it thru your Viber(tested on iOS and Android).

### How I did it:

1. Fount a contact number that I wanted to see his/her name
2. Remover it off my local contact list
3. Opened Viber and Navigated to **More**, followed by **Add Contact**
4. Entered the contact number and pressed **Done** (on iOS)
   Please note that it does not add the contact, nor it notifies the recipient anyhow of the resonance of it's public name.